# Align two images to bottom left & right corners of a <div>

Tags: html, css

My page currently has something a bit like the following, in order to put two images on each side of my page header-bar.

```
    <div id="header" >
        <div style="float:left" >
            <img src="media/logo1.png"/>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right" >
            <img src="media/logo2.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

While this works on the left-right alignment, I can't find a good tweak to get both images aligned to the bottom of the parent `<div>`. They seem to align to the top instead.

However I reckon this might be just the wrong approach to start with. Therefore all suggestions welcome on the best way to make it work - or better, how to arbitrarily force an image to a chosen corner of the parent `<div>`.

Answer (score 7):

If your header has a fixed height, just use absolute positioning:

```
<div id="header" >
    <img id="logo1" src="media/logo1.png"/>
    <img id="logo2" src="media/logo2.png"/>
</div>
```

Then in your CSS:

```
#header     { position: relative; height: 200px}
#header img { position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0}
#logo2      { left: auto; right: 0}
```

**Or**, If your header is only as tall as `logo1.png` then use this CSS instead:

```
#header     { position: relative;}
#logo2      { position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0}
```

This will cause `logo1` to set the height of `header` and `logo2` will just sit at the bottom of `header` and on the right.

Comment: This is screwing up for me; header's parent div is position:absolute and changing header's position from the default takes it out of the normal flow... the div below header (the main content div) is moved up and drawn overlapping header.

Answer (score 1):

You can use margin-top property in the child divs:

```
<div id="header" >
        <div style="float:left; margin-top:20px" >
            <img src="media/logo1.png"/>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right; margin-top:20px" >
            <img src="media/logo2.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this CSS

```
#header {width: 980px; position: relative; height: 300px;}
#header .left {position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;}
#header .right {position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;}
```

and code

```
<div id="header">
  <div class="left">
      <img src="img1.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
      <img src="img2.jpg"/>
  </div>
</div>
```